# Having trouble with camera IOS8 / Swift with Card.IO

Tags: swift, card.io

When I try and scan a card with Card.IO. it does not bring up the camera let alone the green lines around it. When I run this code and press the button it does not show the camera in the view controller. Any ideas ? The sample works fine in io8 in obj-C .

```
@IBAction func PressScan(sender: AnyObject) {

    var CardScanner : CardIOPaymentViewController = CardIOPaymentViewController()
    CardScanner.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen
    self.presentViewController(CardScanner, animated: true, completion: nil)




}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    CardIOPaymentViewController.preload()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func userDidProvideCreditCardInfo(cardInfo: CardIOCreditCardInfo!, inPaymentViewController paymentViewController: CardIOPaymentViewController!) {

}

func userDidCancelPaymentViewController(paymentViewController: CardIOPaymentViewController!) {

}
```

Is there something in the plist file I need to amend to allow camera access for iOS8 ?

Comment: Jason could you please reply to my response to your same question over here: https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/76 -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here: https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/76#issuecomment-65856792

Namely:

> You are not initializing CardIOPaymentViewController correctly. It should be
>
> var CardScanner : CardIOPaymentViewController = CardIOPaymentViewController(paymentDelegate: self)